# prove that the number $38^n+31$ is composite

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for every positive integer $n$, $38^n+31$ is a composite number. for example $38+31=69$ is composite. $38^2+31=1475$ is also composite. I have tried modulo but it didn't work.

Comment: Well,it is divisible by 3 for odd n.

Comment: Someone has asked a similar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/597234/59379) a few month ago. We don't know whether this is true or not. However, according to some comments there, $38^n + 31$ is composite for $n \le 220,000$.

Comment: @achille,is this question suitable for MO?

Comment: @Satvik,pray tell us where you have got this problem from.

Comment: My friend had given me this problem.

Comment: @rah4927 No idea, I'm not a mathematician ;-p But the other question has been there for a few months with 60 up-votes. If one points that out and rephrase the question properly, it is possible MO will accept it.

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate - maybe this question would be better merged with the previous one though.

Answer (score 1):

For odd $n$, take modulo $3$. For even $n$, if $n \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, take modulo $5$. So only $n \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ case remains. (We can further break it up into the cases $12n+4,12n+8,12n$ with modulo $7$..)

Anyway, it is hard to get a conclusive answer out of these types of problems....

Comment: What about this case?

Comment: As noted in a comment this case as already been asked and it hasn't been solved yet, look the other question for more details