# Showing that $38^n+31$ is prime

Tags: number-theory

I was reading a question in one of the previous pages, in searching for a proof I stumble across what seem like a contradiction. All I want is for someone to provide the missing link in my argument.

**The question**

> Find the least $n$ for which $38^n+31$ is prime.

**My attempt at a proof**

If $38^n+31$ composite, then there exist at least a prime $p$ such that $p|38^n+31$. Now $\gcd(p,38)=1$, otherwise, $d=\gcd(p,38)=2$ or $19$ and $d|31$ a contradiction. Hence, by Fermat's Little Theorem; 
$38^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, and for all positive integer $r$, $38^{r(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Hence, $38^{r(p-1)}+31 \equiv 32 \pmod p$, but $38^{r(p-1)}+31 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, because it's composite. It follows that $32 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ i.e $p|32$, a contradiction, and hence, the above expression cannot be composite (but inputing real values for $n$ shows that it is indeed composite).

Comment: You went astray in $38^rp-1\equiv1 \pmod p$. How did you arrived there?

Comment: What exactly are you doing to the equivalence $38^{p-1}\equiv1$ to get $38^{rp-1}\equiv1$?

Comment: It also seems to me that you have actually "concluded" that no prime $p$ divides $38^n+31$ at all. So you're not just "proving" that it is not composite, but also that it is not prime. So it's not anything?

Comment: Is the issue that by $38^{rp-1}$ you actually mean $38^{r(p-1)}$?

Comment: @alex, that's what i meant, just that i have typing problems

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597234/least-prime-of-the-form-38n31

Comment: I think you've assumed that $n=r(p-1)$ for some $r$, which need not be the case, in the third to last line.

Comment: Agree with Alex Jordan, Bryan and kingW3. You have only shown that $n$ cannot be a multiple of $p-1$. So for a given $p$ we need to use a different $n$, but is there some $n$ that does not work for any $p$ (non-trivially)?

Answer (score 4):

It does not follow that $38^rp-1\equiv 1\pmod p$. In fact $38^rp-1\equiv -1\pmod p$. And how are you trying to get from $38^rp-1+31$ to $38^n+31$ anyway?

Comment: It's a typo error, i've corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $p-1\not=1$ since expression is odd,so $p\geq3$ clearly the expression doesn't cover the whole $\mathbb{N}$,you would have to prove these cases also $$r(p-1)+i,i=1,2,3\cdots p-2$$

Answer (score 0):

For $38^x+31$, it is useful to note that the small primes divide $38^x+1$, as $x$ is odd or double-odd.  So, eg $3 \mid 38^x+1 $ for odd x.  $5 \mid 3d^x + 1$ for $x=2 \pmod 4$.  So after removing 3 and 5, one is left with $4 \mid x$.

Running through the output of `factor` for $38^{4x}+31$, gives some rather difficult numbers to factorise.  for x=3, there are three divisors, 338431, 322249, and 83126873.

It's probably not an easy row to hoe here.  There well may be primes, but these are not generally accessable.  `factor` seems to indicate that if it were prime, then $4x\gt 176$