# On composite-ness of numbers of certain form

Tags: number-theory

If $a\ge750$ is an integer  , then is it true that $\bigl(2\times17^{4a+3}\bigr)+1$  cannot be a prime ?

Comment: Is this ever an integer?

Comment: Is that period a multiplication sign? I guess so (seen it enough many times), but that always leaves me wondering? Sorry about the tag see-saw. The only thing I can tell easily is that if $a\equiv1\pmod 3$, then the number is divisible by seven.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597234/least-prime-of-the-form-38n31).

Answer (score 0):

$2*17^{4*1497+3}+1$ is prime.

So the answer is very short: No.

Edit: 
There are some good tools to search for primes. I used these:

1. For Sieving you can use NewPGen: http://primes.utm.edu/programs/NewPGen/
2. And for the actual proving of primality there is LLR: http://jpenne.free.fr/

Comment: The begging question : How do you know that ?