# $2^{8420} - 9$ is prime or not

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

How to prove $2^{8420} - 9$ is or isn't a prime number?

I tried modding it by 10 to get the last digit, but that's a 7 which doesn't help.

We've only been covering successive squaring in this chapter (and modular arithmetic).

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597234) question. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the factorization $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ for a useful choice of values for $a$ and $b$.

When you do this, it should be fairly obvious that both factors are bigger than $1$.

Comment: `2^(8420) = 2^(2*4210)(2^4210)^2`
and
`2^(8420) - 9 = 
(2^4210)^2 - 3^2 =  
(2^4210-3)(2^4210+3)`
...
  So this shows I have found 2 factors that are not the number itself and 1. Proving that this number is not prime. Is this the most correct way to show this?

Comment: That is one correct way to show that $2^{8420}-9$ is not prime, but of course, there are other ways as well.

Answer (score 2):

The number is a multiple of $13$ because $2^{12} \equiv 1 \bmod 13$, $8240 \equiv 8 \bmod 12$, and $2^8 \equiv 9 \bmod 13$.

Comment: The smallest prime factors of $2^{8420} - 9$ are $13$, $21649$, $2201539$, ...