# Prove or disprove that ${F_{n}}^2 + 41$ is always a composite (if $F_{n}$ is $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, fibonacci-numbers

The problem is as follows:

> Prove or disprove: If $F_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number then $${F_{n}}^2 + 41$$
> is always a composite number.

It looks that if $n$ is not multiple of 12, ${F_{n}}^2 + 41$ is divisible by $2$, $3$, or $5$. If $n$ is multiple of 12, however, some interesting, unusual, cases appear:

$${F_{12}}^2 + 41 = 79 \times 263$$

$${F_{72}}^2 + 41 = 9749 \times 25485321772339055988195013$$

$${F_{108}}^2 + 41 = 5119 \times 1317671 \times 41055200011068517359399666969411793$$

$${F_{204}}^2 + 41 = 5 \times 6400350375910983011604271319374598934759558555511500080780194261$$

Using `PrimeQ[]`, Mathematica says that ${F_{n}}^2 + 41$ is composite for $n < 10000$.

This is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090319/is-f-n2-28-always-a-composite-number) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092024/prove-or-disprove-that-f-n2-43-is-always-a-composite) question.

My intuitive feeling is that for some large $n$, ${F_{n}}^2 + 41$ is prime.

Comment: Try the case  $n=12588$

Comment: I have posted this in [our big list of conjectures with large counterexamples](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111440/examples-of-apparent-patterns-that-eventually-fai).

Comment: Related (indirectly): 
 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As soon as I posted the question, Mathematica reported that there is one case of $n$ between $10000$ and $20000$ where the expression in question is prime!

The case is $n=12588$.

That's cool! This can serve as an educational real-world example that it is not enough to check first 10000 cases. That's why I won't delete this question and answer, although the suspense lasted only few minutes...

Comment: There are many cases where large $n$ counter-examples exist, see for example [this big-list answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples).

Comment: Checking small cases is important, but so is understanding the underlying theory. Sooner or later Mathematica will crash on you just shy of a counterexample. And there will be other cases in which it might be enough to check the first hundred cases before you figure out why no counterexample can exist. If only I had my own copy of Hosoya's book!