# (Unsolved) In this infinite sequence, no term is a prime: prove/disprove.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

$ 343,~ 34343, ~3434343, ~343434343,\ldots$

$\begin{array}\\
\color{Red}{343} &\color{Red}{: 7^3}\\
34343  &: 61\times 563\\
\color{green}{3434343} &\color{green}{: 3\times 11^2\times 9461}\\
\color{red}{343434343} &\color{Red}{: 7\times 521\times 94169}\\
34343434343 &: 47\times 79\times 9249511\\
\color{green}{3434343434343} &\color{green}{: 3^2\times 19\times 29\times  67\times10336531}\\
\color{red}{343434343434343} &\color{Red}{: 7\times 151\times 324914232199}\\
34343434343434343 &: 5638147\times 6091262669
\end{array}$

***Update:*** The numbers in black are,

$$F_n = \frac{34\times10^{6n-1}-43}{99}$$

and $F_n$ is composite for $n<1667$ (user *Uncountable*) and $n<3101$ (user *A.P.*).

Comment: It's easy to prove that one third of the numbers are divisible by 3, and another third are divisible by 7.

Comment: It's only the black ones that are of interest.

Comment: Where did you find the problem??????

Comment: one of my friend told me

Comment: The black numbers are of the form $(34\times10^n+43)/99$ where $n$ is of the form $6r-1$. That doesn't solve the problem, but it gives you a more convenient form for the numbers.

Comment: There exist no primes of this form up to $3434\cdots 3$ with $10^4+1$ digits.

Comment: The black sequence is showing any pattern ?

Comment: The next black numbers factorize into: $$227\times 14683\times 206897\times 49802239559$$ $$11\times 129368501\times 24133621173037071713$$ $$97\times 77237\times 20966234861723\times 218638251212369$$ $$29\times 1184256356670149773598049460118425635667$$ $$197\times 7643\times 307147\times 557307084359\times 133251711287229640618021$$ $$3710532169\times 9255662740336787371036382016995347988409647$$ $$2617\times 5106108771231877\times 16443695443593833\times 156296953619492510022619$$ $$61\times 257\times 20393\times 56687\times 157619853435931\times 12022789731913276847497978482161743279$$

Comment: @RK, if you want someone to notice a comment of yours, and the comment is not below an answer placed by that person, you need to begin the comment with an @ sign and, at least, the first three letters of that person's username.

Comment: Ok, thanks for informing.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson That should be a minus there. The black numbers are of the form: $$\frac{34\times 10^{6n-1}-43}{99}$$

Comment: It's worth noting that since this sequence is exponential, it satisfies a linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients, and so some of the tools that have been applied to those sequences might be applicable here.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090319/is-f-n2-28-always-a-composite-number/ for an example.

Comment: Waiting for the Proof!

Comment: Guys, i have found  an observation that $\frac{34\times 10^{6n-1}-43}{99}\pmod 6=-1$

Comment: Just for fun, I checked the first 3101 terms of the (interesting) sequence with Sage and none of them is prime...

Comment: @Uncountable: There is a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235283/). Care to check for its primality up to a certain range?

Answer (score 7):

We have $343434 = 2 \times 3 \times 7 \times 13 \times 17 \times 37$. $34343$ is not divisible by any of these numbers. Therefore the subsequence $34343$, $34343 + 343434 \times 10^5$, $34343 + 343434 \times 10^5 \times (10^0 + 10^6)$, $34343 + 343434 \times 10^5 \times (10^0 + 10^6 + 10^{12})$, $34343 + 343434 \times 10^5 \times (10^0 + 10^6 + 10^{12} + 10^{18})$ etc. consists of numbers which are not divisible by $2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, \quad \text{or}\quad  37$.

Heuristically, the chance of a random number $N$ being prime is $1 / \ln N$. Having $7$ small primes excluded as possible factors increases the chances by a factor $(2/1)(3/2)(5/4)(7/6)(13/12)(17/16)(37/36) ≈ 5.1757$.

The numbers are around $3.4343 \times 10^{5+6k}$ with $k = 0, 1, 2, 3,\ldots$ The natural logarithm is about $13.8155k + 10.4442$. So the chance that each of the numbers is a prime is about $5.1757 / (13.8155k + 10.4442)$. The expected number of primes among the numbers for $k = 0$ to $n$ is about $0.3746 \cdot\ln (n) + 0.4013$. For $n = 1,666$ the expected number of primes is about $3.1803$; that's the range that Uncountable checked. So finding no primes is slightly unlucky, but not that unlikely.

For a $50\%$ chance of finding a prime, the expected number of primes needs to increase by $\ln 2 ≈ 0.6931$, so $\ln n$ needs to be increased by $0.6931/0.3746 ≈ 1.8502$, $n$ needs to be multiplied by $6.36$. So there's a $50\%$ chance of finding a prime with up to $63,600$ digits; then a $50\%$ chance for a prime with up to $404,000$ digits and so on.

Of course all that is just heuristic. If it is correct, then a prime will almost certainly exist. Finding a probable prime might be very hard. If checking a range that gives a $50\%$ chance fails, the next range giving a $50\%$ chance is $6.36$ times larger. Miller-Rabin test grows more than quadratic with the number of digits, and there are more numbers to test, so the next range takes more than $6.36^3 = 257$ times longer.

Comment: Can you look at this [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235283/) and give a comment why $7373737373737\dots$ has prime values for $n=3,\,7,\,95,\,422,\dots$.