# Numbers $717, 71717, 7171717,\dots$ and primality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> *Prove or disprove that all numbers $717, 71717, 7171717,\dots$  are composite.*

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159434/unsolvedin-this-infinite-sequence-no-term-is-a-prime-prove-disprove?lq=1).

$\begin{array}\\
717 &= \text{div by 3}\\
\color{blue}{71717} &= 29\cdot 2473\\
7171717 &= \text{div by 7}\\
717171717 &= \text{div by 3}\\
\color{blue}{71717171717} &= 857\cdot83683981\\
7171717171717 &= \text{div by 7}\\
717171717171717 &= \text{div by 3}\\
\color{blue}{71717171717171717} &= 11\cdot239\cdot2011\cdot13565021843\\
\end{array}$

***Q: Is the subsequence in blue always composite?***

---

*Note 1:* The numbers in blue are

$$F_n = \frac{71\times10^{6n-1}-17}{99}$$

and $F_n$ is composite for $n<5000$ (user *Uncountable*).

Also, $F_8=71717171717171717171717171717171717171717171717 =35972094619010351911⋅1993689065836910882277192947$

---

*Note 2:* For similar $737,73737,7373737,\dots$

$$P_n = \frac{73\times10^{6n-3}-37}{99}$$

$P_3 = 737373737373737$ is prime and $P_n$ is ***prime*** for $n = 3,7,95,422,2390$ for $n<5250$ (user *Uncountable*).

Comment: I've revised your question to be analogous to the link you provided.

Comment: For Note 2, we have, $$P_n = \frac{73\cdot10^{6n-3}-37}{99}$$ and for $n<23$ is prime for $n=3,7$. **Question**: Is it necessarily the case that for $P_n$ (or $F_n$) to be prime, then $n$ must be prime? (I assume it is just coincidence, but I thought I should ask.)

Comment: *Is the subsequence in brown always composite ?* - No.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597234) question.

Comment: Also, if $a_0=7$ and $a_{n+1}=100~a_n+17$, then there are no primes for $n\le5,000$.