# $2^i - 2293$ is always composite?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Is $2^i - 2293$ always composite for $i=1,2,3,...$ ?

I have known: if $2^i - 2293$ is prime, $i$ must have the form $i = 24 k+1$

`In[2]:= Table[FactorInteger[2^i - 2293], {i, 1, 241, 24}]`

Out[2]= {{{-1, 1}, {29, 1}, {79, 1}}, {{173, 1}, {193943, 
   1}}, {{6737807, 1}, {83550917, 1}}, {{399550573, 
   1}, {23638391743063, 1}}, {{281, 1}, {14821, 1}, {24203, 
   1}, {3712421, 1}, {423447263633, 1}}, {{149, 1}, {9492181, 
   1}, {1879650895890301462105483811, 1}}, {{137, 1}, {2683, 
   1}, {2360851, 1}, {2808601, 1}, {2020240309, 1}, {9058295304389951,
    1}}, {{23, 1}, {29, 1}, {107, 1}, {199, 1}, {21035159, 
   1}, {5797034797, 1}, {28376991193, 1}, {15226094729816791, 
   1}}, {{526557780757, 1}, {1946642765756893, 
   1}, {12247765663995514289321022531499, 1}}, {{47, 1}, {617, 
   1}, {160191103, 1}, {8207681257, 1}, {9477520181923, 
   1}, {46405673331331, 1}, {12560339159195827, 1}}, {{439, 
   1}, {80494171516099513876232232380087403910135940632146649572738323\
52130381, 1}}}

Comment: $$|2^n-2293|$$ is composite for $1\le n\le 200,000$, so a prime of the desired form must have more than $60,000$ digits.

Comment: Where does $2293$ come from?

Comment: I conjectured that any odd number 2n+1=2^i+p, p is a (maybe negative) prime. however puzzled by 2293. It seems this conjecture is FALSE. http://2293.ml is my math site,(little info yet now!)

Comment: I still tend to believe that there are primes (in fact infinite many primes) of the form $2^n-2293$.  The situation is similar with Wieferich-primes, for example. They are unbelievable rare, but is believed that infinite many exist. But $2293$ is very tough indeed. :)

Comment: @DanaJ , here is another project for you. Find a prime of the form $2^n-2293$ ! As you can see, I searched upto about $n=200,000$ without success.

Comment: It appears that $2293$ is interesting for another, related reason: https://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php/2293.html says: *"The smallest number $k$ for which there is no known prime of the form $k\cdot2^n−1$."* Note also that if one slightly changes the requirement, changing $2^i-2293$ to $2^i+2293$ then it becomes easy: $2^2+2293=2297$, a prime :) @user37238

Comment: I am currently at $n=270,000$, no primes yet! A prime of the desired form must have more then $80,000$ digits!

Comment: I have passed $n=300,000$ now. No primes found yet! I will continue upto $100,000$ digits.

Comment: @Peter, I think that no primes of form |2^i-2293|. I see you are searching Least prime of the form 38^n+31 (http://adf.ly/1S7PWf).  I also tend to believe no prime of the form 38^n+31

Comment: sagemath:<code>300000%24 == 0
i = 300000 + 1
while not is_prime(2^i - 2293):
    print(i)
    i += 24
</code>

Comment: @a boy, please replace your commercialized link (at adf.ly) by the direct link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597234/least-prime-of-the-form-38n31 . After I have followed your link I have now a "cookie" from that people on my computer which I have to find and delete manually

Comment: @a boy as I already mentioned, I think that primes of both forms exists, unless there is a special reason that it is impossible. Of course, the smallest such prime can have millions of digits. But the functions grow slowly enough that heuristics lead to the conjecture that there are primes.

Comment: I clicked the link above. Is this safe, or can I receive unwelcome cookies this way ?

Comment: @gottfried helms how can I find out whether such cookies (only deletable manually) are on my computer ?

Comment: @Peter: I just found that cookie using "Extras/Einstellungen/..."  and then the register card for manual cookie-deletion.(I don't know for what reason/goal, but firefox uses one of the most uncomfortable windows I've ever seen for long lists to check/manipulate, so don't get exhausted too early)

Comment: i<=300121, no prime of the form 2^i-2293. It taken a whole afternoon to work out  (300 000, 300 121) on cloud.sagemath.com. 3x @Peter

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, I always neglect cookie. Before html5 born, there were cookies all over.the world. thanks for your kind attention

Comment: According to my calculation, a prime of the desired form must have more than $100,000$ digits. Someone might check and approve this ...

Comment: If there is a witness (a fixed product of primes) that is not coprime to $2^N - 2293$  for each natural $N$, then the period of $2$ in that witness is a multiple of either $3368903$ or $83550916$, based on the factors of $2^{49}-2293$

Comment: Turns out people have been looking for quite a while.  E.g. [Mersenneforum 2009](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=183260&postcount=15) and [Mersenneforum 2010](http://mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=13807).  I haven't seen any results however.  I've checked to n=360k, which is ~108k digits.

Comment: This post from 2010: [mersenneforum](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=227674&postcount=1159) as well as [an earlier one](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=227599&postcount=1136) says it's been tested to over 700k.  So over 210k digits.

Comment: Does anyone known what range has been checked as of 2020?

Comment: $2293$ is also the smallest unsolved candidate for a [Riesel Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RieselNumber.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a part of [The dual Riesel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesel_number#The_dual_Riesel_problem), and is an open problem.

This problem is related to [The Riesel problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RieselNumber.html), which consists in determining the smallest Riesel number: a number $k$ such that $k\cdot 2^n - 1$ is not prime for any integer $n$. The smallest unsolved candidate for this is $2293$. (The smallest known Riesel number  is $509203$.)

The dual Riesel numbers are defined as the odd natural numbers $k$ such that $|2^n - k|$ is composite for all natural numbers $n$. The smallest unsolved candidates for these numbers are $1871$ and $2293$.

There is a conjecture that the set of dual Riesel numbers is the same as the set of Riesel numbers.

The problem of Riesel numbers dates back to year $1956$. ([post on Primegrid](http://www.primegrid.com/forum_thread.php?id=1731).)